# How do I create a reverse proxy in apache/nginx for a spring boot multitenant app

Tags: java, spring-boot, reverse-proxy, multi-tenant, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am required to create a POC for a multi-tenant app in spring boot which ready. I need to configure a proxy to pass tenant name to tomcat app server. This name is used in distinguish the the tenant. The default tenant is app. The tenant names are dynamic. It is similar to what Shopify does where each store name is storename.shopify.com .

E.g for app1.example.com. The proxy should forward app1 to spring, for app2.example.com; proxy should forward app2 to spring ?

Comment: This sounds like a normal vhost nginx setup

Answer (score 0):

A simple reverse proxy configuration pointing to a running springboot app solves it. In my spring app, I retrieve header information to show information for each tenant.

Reverse Proxy Configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@mydomain.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    #ServerAlias *.mydomain.com


    ProxyPreserveHost  On
    ProxyPass  / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse  / http://127.0.0.1:8082

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Spring Boot Config for retrieving server information

```
String schemeName = httpServletRequest.getScheme();     
String serverName = httpServletRequest.getServerName();
```